# Angular2 reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators

Tags: angular, angular2-universal

I’m trying to use the universal starter example to learn more about server rendering with Angular2, I want to use gulp instead of webpack. 
The problem is when the server start I have :

```
/Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/trails-angular2-isomorphic/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/decorators.js:165
        throw 'reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators';
        ^
reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators
```

I see some posts who said to add `import 'reflect-metadata';` but that doesn’t fix the issue for me :( I think I miss something but can’t figure what it is...
Here is the code I use https://github.com/jaumard/trails-angular2-isomorphic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact the `import 'reflect-metadata';` have to be added on my server.ts file as I want to use server rendering. After adding it. No more errors.

Answer (score 2):

This error is because, just like directive, your component HTML should be enclosed in a div.

```
<div>
//html
</div>
```

I got the same issue. When I enclose the HTML inside the div, it's working fine.